# Finding errors in LaTeX document, java

Tags: java, parsing, error-handling, command, latex

So I have a bunch of LaTeX styled documents, one looks like this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\begin{document}
    {\Large \begin{center} Homework Problems \end{center}}\begin{itemize}\item\end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
            \item Prove: For all sets $A$ and $B$, $(A - B) \cup
                    (A \cap B) = A$.
                    \begin{proof}
                            \begin{align}
                                    & (A - B) \cup (A \cap B) && \\
                                    & = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B) && \text{by
                                    Alternate Definition of Set Difference} \\
                                    & = A \cap (B^c \cup B) && \text{by Distributive Law} \\
                                    & = A \cap (B \cup B^c) && \text{by Commutative Law} \\
                                    & = A \cap U && \text{by Union with the Complement Law} \\
                                    & = A && \text{by Intersection with $U$ Law}
                            \end{align}
                    \end{proof}
            \item If $n = 4k + 3$, does 8 divide $n^2 - 1$?
                    \begin{proof}
                            Let $n = 4k + 3$ for some integer $k$. Then
                            \begin{align}
                                    n^2 - 1 & = (4k + 3)^2 - 1 \\
                                    & = 16k^2 + 24k + 9 - 1 \\
                                    & = 16k^2 + 24k + 8 \\
                                    & = 8(2k^2 + 3k + 1) \text{,}
                            \end{align}
                            which is certainly divisible by 8.
                    \end{proof}
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

Now first I had to read through each document and line and find all of the "\begin{BLOCK}" and "\end{BLOCK}" commands and add the BLOCK string to a Stack and when I found the matching "\end" I would call the pop() command on my Stack. I pretty much got all that done, it's just not well organized, or at least I think there is a better way to go about it than all my "if" statements. So that is my first question, is there something better than the way I did it?

Next is I want to find errors and report them. For example, if I removed the line "\begin{document}" from the text above, I want the program to run through, do everything it is suppose to, but when It reaches the line "\end{document}" it reports the missing "\begin" command. I got my code to handle other examples, such as removing the "\begin" commands for enumerate or itemize, but I can't get that case to work.

Finally I want to be able to handle missing "\end" commands. I have made an attempt at it but I can't quite get the conditioning right. Let's say I have this document...

```
\begin{argument}
\begin{Palin}No it can't. An argument is a connected series of statements intended to establish a proposition.\end{Palin}
\begin{Cleese}No it isn't.\end{Cleese}
\begin{Palin}\expression{exclamation}Yes it is! It's not just contradiction.\end{Palin}
\begin{Cleese}Look, if I argue with you, I must take up a contrary position.\end{Cleese}
\begin{Palin}Yes, but that's not just saying \begin{quotation}'No it isn't.'\end{Palin}
\begin{Cleese}\expression{exclamation}Yes it is!\end{Cleese}
\begin{Palin}\expression{exclamation}No it isn't!\end{Palin}
\begin{Cleese}\expression{exclamation}Yes it is!\end{Cleese}
\begin{Palin}Argument is an intellectual process.  Contradiction is just the automatic gainsaying of any statement the other person makes.\end{Palin}
\end{argument}
```

You'll notice on line 6 there is a "\begin{quotation}" command without an "\end". My code when going through this particular document gives me this as output...

```
PARSE ERROR Line 6: Missing command \begin{Palin}.
PARSING TERMINATED!
```

This is obviously not true, but I don't know how to restructure my error handling to get these cases to work. Can anyone provide any help? Especially in the way of organizing this code to better suite it for finding these issues.

-------------------------------------------CODE-------------------------------------------

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class LaTeXParser{

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Stack s = new Stack();

    int lineCount = 0;

    String line;
    String nextData = null;
    String title = null;

            String fname;

            System.out.print("Enter the name of the file (no extension): ");
            fname = scan.next();

            fname = fname + ".txt";

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fname);

            Scanner fscan = new Scanner(fstream);

            System.out.println();

            while(fscan.hasNextLine()){

                lineCount++;
                line = fscan.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);

                while(tok.hasMoreElements()){

                    nextData = tok.nextToken();
                    System.out.println("The line: "+nextData);

                    if(nextData.contains("\\begin") && !nextData.contains("\\end")){

                        if(nextData.charAt(1) == 'b'){

                            title = nextData.substring(nextData.indexOf("{") + 1, nextData.indexOf("}"));

                            s.push(title);

                        }
                    }//end of BEGIN if

                    if(nextData.contains("\\end") && !nextData.contains("\\begin")){

                        String[] theLine = nextData.split("[{}]");

                        for(int i = 0 ; i < theLine.length ; i++){

                            if(theLine[i].contains("\\end") && !s.isEmpty() && theLine[i+1].equals(s.peek())){

                                s.pop();

                                i++;

                            }

                            if(theLine[i].contains("\\end") && !theLine[i+1].equals(s.peek())){

                                System.out.println("PARSE ERROR Line " + lineCount + ": Missing command \\begin{" + theLine[i+1] + "}.");
                                System.out.println("PARSING TERMINATED!");
                                System.exit(0);

                            }
                        }
                    }//end of END if

                    if(nextData.contains("\\begin") && nextData.contains("\\end")){

                        String[] theLine = nextData.split("[{}]");

                        for(int i = 0 ; i < theLine.length ; i++){

                            if(theLine[i].contains("\\end") && theLine[i+1].equals(s.peek())){

                                s.pop();

                            }

                            if(theLine[i].equals("\\begin")){

                                title = theLine[i+1];

                                s.push(title);
                            }
                        }
                    }//end of BEGIN AND END if
                }
            }//end of whiles

            fscan.close();

    if(s.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(fname + " LaTeX file is valid!");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    while(!s.isEmpty()){



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you (re) writing a latex parser ? Can't you find your needs in existing tools ?

Comment: It's just a simple assignment, not looking to do anything drastic or complex. Just read the file and make sure \begin's have \end's and etc.

Comment: The best LaTeX parser is still (La)TeX. Write macros in LaTeX that extract all needed information.